# AngularFire2 RealTime DataBase sort by date value

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

#### My Service

```
get ActivityList():any {
    return this.activityList.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
        return changes.map(c => ({ 
            key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val();
        }));
    });
}
```

#### My Component

```
getActivity() {
    this.activityService.ActivityList.subscribe(activity => {
        this.activity = activity;
    });
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of activity">
    {{item.created|date:'medium'}}
</div>
```

## Question

This is how I am currently getting my activity from Firebase RealTime Database. where and how is the best way to modify this to sort by the `created` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change service to

```
get ActivityList():any {
    return this.activityList.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
        return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() })).sort((a, b) => b.created - a.created );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort it after subscribe.

```
getActivity() {
    this.activityService.ActivityList.subscribe(activity => {
        this.activity = activity.sort((a, b) => a.create - b.create );;
    });
}
```

Comment: working on solving this now `changes.map(...).do is not a function`

Comment: this is not working. Im trying different variations of this.

Comment: just adding my 2 cents, add that sort that sachila wrote in a pipe to have that functionality in other places without adding more code.

Comment: ERROR TypeError: list.sort is not a function  .... also trying the pipe

Comment: grrr, `do` operator should work. Ok i guess u have to sort it inide the subscribe, check the update